# Increment ID in JavaScript object array

Tags: javascript

I'm new in JavaScript programming then I got weird case like this. I have an one Array Object and one Array like below :

```
let data = [{"name": "Apple"} , {"name": "Orange"}, {"name": "Pineapple"}]
let selected = [];
```

I implement click in `data` when item clicked then the selected object in `data` move to `selected`. The data have no ID so I create the ID with its position index in `selected`. But if there is same object the position is same too. I try some code below but it does not work.

1.

```
  const dataObject = {"name": "Apple"};
  dataObject['position'] = selected.length;
  selected.push(dataObject);
```

2. 

```
  const dataObject = {"name": "Apple"};
  selected.push(dataObject);
  for(let i = 0; i<selected.length; i++) {
    selected[i]['position'] = i;
  }
```

The weird case is if there is same object like `Apple, Orange, Apple` , I get the wrong ID in Array like :

```
[{"name": "Apple", position: 2} , {"name": "Orange", position: 1}, {"name": "Apple", position: 2}]
```

### Edit

Here the reproducible code :

```
let data = [{"name": "Apple"} , {"name": "Orange"}, {"name": "Pineapple"}]
let selected = [];

const dataObject = {"name": "Apple"};
selected.push(dataObject);
selected.push(dataObject);
for(let i = 0; i<selected.length; i++) {
  selected[i]['position'] = i;
}

document.write('<br>' + JSON.stringify(selected));

// Output : [{"name":"Apple","position":1},{"name":"Apple","position":1}] 
// Output Expect: [{"name":"Apple","position":0},{"name":"Apple","position":1}]
```

Where might be my mistake?

Comment: Please provide code to reproduce the issue, preferably without the click handler, but just sequentially executed code. Input, expected output, output you get.

Comment: you question is not very clear, if possible, try and update your question with - input data, code and its issue and expected output

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited and rebuild simple version in online editor. Sorry again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dataObject` is assigned by reference in `selected` array, so its the same object you are assigning twice, change in one will change both elements of `selected` array as they are same object.

See if below code helps

```js
let data = [{"name": "Apple"} , {"name": "Orange"}, {"name": "Pineapple"}]
let selected = [];

const dataObject = {"name": "Apple"};

//assigning a new object to selected by using dataObject
selected.push({"name":dataObject.name});

//assigning a new object to selected by using dataObject
selected.push({"name":dataObject.name});

for(let i = 0; i<selected.length; i++) {
  selected[i]['position'] = i;
}

document.write('<br>' + JSON.stringify(selected));
```

Answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference) can get you started to learn more

Comment: I see, so Javascript pass the reference. Its new for me. Thank you for answer and the link